Is there legal metaphor in the Lord's Prayer (Matthew 6:11-13)?
I'd be grateful for some feedback on a subtext I sense in Matthew 6:11-13, at the end of the Lord's Prayer.
My question is from a literary/linguistics perspective and isn't seeking help with "what does the Lord's prayer mean" / "how should we pray" answers - since those are the main reading and stand regardless of a subtext. It's about the presence or otherwise of a colloquial legal metaphor underneath this.
It's also not about how to translate, it's about how to read the Greek.
And I can read Greek, it's whether reading it this way arises from the lack of hermeneutics (in which I have no training except what you're kind enough to share), or entails a heresy.
I assume familiarity with the Greek text, so won't venture to translate or Word-Study beyond setting out the hooks for a reading to hang by.
This is quite long but the gist is brief and hopefully the lexicon references are well-worn ones and can be skim-read
As a new user I'm grateful for your patience
=====================
Mt.6:11 ἐπιούσιον - this is taken as "for the coming day" (Strongs) and if the bread also brings in staple sustenance/livelihood (Ellicott) can this support some sense of 'give us tomorrow's bread today' or by extension 'lend us some cash'. Didomi could be used of loans and monetary payments (e.g. Mt.25:15).
I'll use "money" for the subtextual reading but that's to bring out the subtext in English, it doesn't matter if it's a debt of (sustaining) bread, particularly since this isn't about the translation
==
Mt.6:12 ὀφειλήματα - to this is given greater reference back to 6:11. 'Lend us some money and let us off the debt in the last verse'. So a big ask.
==
Mt.6:12 καὶ ἡμεῖς ἀφήκαμεν - a consecutive sense of kai behind the primary comparison it introduces. And we forgave those we lent your money to.
So we've borrowed some money, and we're asking to be let off paying it back, because we lent it to someone else and then (foolishy) let them off paying us back. Which takes it from "big ask" to "worst case".
==
Mt.6:13 εἰσενέγκῃς ἡμᾶς εἰς πειρασμόν - for πειρασμόν there can't be found a strong sense of a court claim, but we might expect a speaker in this situation to employ understatement or to put emphasis on the claimant 'trying' something when really it's them who hasn't a leg to stand on.
==
Mt.6:13 ῥῦσαι - to deliver/rescue, from archaic ῥέω flow run stream gush melt away drop off including of words, or Heraclitus' followers are nicknamed "gushers" because they believe all things are 'in flux'. Rarely (Lidell & Scott usage II) to let flow or pour. Which offers 'let us off the burden' 'let it flow away' i.e. 'fuhgeddaboudit'. It might imply the flowing of Christ's blood by which the debt will be indeed forgiven.
==
Mt.6:13 πονηροῦ - evil (or the evil one), the Greek idea was more about burden/hardship. Thucydides: poneros echein for an army to be in a bad state for grain.
Arndt&Gringrich have one example of poneria for punishment of wickedness (Hs 9,18,1).
There is a resemblance to the root of Lat:poena and our word 'penalty' but this comes from Gk. poine which is traced to a PIE root meaning to pay. Ponos though is traced to a different PIE root meaning to stretch or strain. (https://archive.org/details/etymological-dictionary-of-greek_202306/page/n611/mode/2up). And yet: πονηρός might be a quite natural word for an adverse court finding, hearing fee, obligation, etc without needing echoes of other words. We know what the courts hand down to Jesus will be Evil per se.
=====================
This draws out a tenuous subtext like:
'please lend us some money; let us off the debt because we lent it on to someone else (whom we've let off); and don't please try to reclaim it; oh and could we have a waiver to that effect'
It would have a comedic escalation
As an image it's capable of being reconciled with the doctrine of salvation-through-grace: since when the book is inevitably thrown at us we'll be left needing to ask our counsel (or worse the judge's Son!), to pay the debt. It would cohere with and unite the figures of the Forgiving Father and the Judge.
I don't see it to complicate the difference with Luke's version (Lk.11:4)
It assumes πονηρός is concrete but I don't think it makes that obligatory for the main reading
In the free/online commentaries on Biblehub, Matthew Henry makes a countervailing point that: "We beg of God to give it us; not sell it us, nor lend it us, but give it." but this reading would be a request for a loan that reduces to a request for a gift
Otherwise those commentaries don't throw up any particular obstacles to the proposed subtext
By way of a converse, there might be implied an equivalence between our trespasses (in the main reading) and (in the subtext) some idea of foolishly handing what God has given us over to Satan.
====
Again thank you for reading

Is this a question, a statement or a sermon?

@Dottard I'll venture: a humorous reference to Matthew 5:18, about ἰ and ; being the same number of jots. And if this is an essential point of difference between us to boot, then it works rather well. +1

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question.

@RayButterworth my apologies I'm new here and would have been glad to have had the protocol explained to me before votes. I hadn't intended to be rude or unhelpful to answerers, I only assumed it would be sufficient for them if I put "it's whether reading it this way arises from the lack of hermeneutics" in the Question box, with It's referring to the question. I pray my rephrasing of the title will be of sufficient assistance.

There is no offense taken - we are all friends here.  The problem with this is the great difficulty in deciding what you are asking amongst the huge statement you make.  I cannot work out what you are asking.  Please try to be concise.

So, you have some information @FelixLXX if you haven't take a moment to take the site tour and check out info for new users and the FAQs. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

@FelixLXX For formatting tips please look at this meta post on Formatting and see Avoiding the 'Great Wall of Textus ' for brevity.

I'm afraid the OP, despite a good bit of research, may be barking up the wrong tree here. "Debts" are not literal debts or outstanding loans in these verses; they are metaphors for sins and crimes. We are not taught to pray for forgiveness from actual debts - whether owed to God or man - but for forgiveness from sin. This is clarified two lines later by the following:

14 For if ye forgive men their trespasses, your heavenly Father will
also forgive you. 15 But if ye forgive not men their trespasses,
neither will your Father forgive your trespasses.

The debt owed to God is not a legal one. The issue is relational - a matter of heart, not law. Our sins have broken out relationship with God and his grace enables its restoration. The same is true with regard of our forgiveness of others. Jesus is not teaching us to forget actual loans owed to us, but forgive our brothers and sisters who have sinned against us.

I was at pains to highlight the primary and a subtextual reading. ὀφειλήματα could mean literal debts, and must - for the metaphor of the primary reading to be drawn from them. So it needs to be shown how the writer excludes a nuance toward literal debts. At 6:14-15 the clarification introduced with 'for'=γάρ only extends the simplex without closing the converse: as might a supplementary " 'but'=ἀλλά I don't mean about literal debt"

but thank you. I bark at every tree I come to, in case the birds have any crumbs

Sorry for being stingy with the crumbs this time. I imagine that simpler questions will yield more fruit. ;-)
